# Is there a way to disable safe_mode in a client or domain template in Plesk?

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, safe-mode

Is there a way to disable the PHP setting safe_mode in a client or domain template in Plesk 8.6? Or, to disable it for new domain creation in some other Plesk setting/configuration?

- I've Googled, and people seem to think no
- I've asked our hosting provider, and they don't think so
- I've looked in both the domain and client templates in Plesk and don't see it

Has anyone been able to do this Plesk 8.6 for new domains?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in Plesk 9.2.  I highly suspect that the behavior works the same in 8.6.

Using your favorite MySQL interface, login as **`admin`**, using your Plesk administrator password, then look at the results of:

```
USE psa;
DESCRIBE hosting;
```

Look for the field: **`php_safe_mode`**. The default is **`true`**.

I believe that if you set the default to **`false`**, you will achieve what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work in 8.6.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer cause it's very helpful for Plesk 9+. Thanks again!